# Will the hole drilled into the furnace door cause problems? Gases etc. escaping?

Tags: furnace

I recently had a furnace service. A 3 blink code came up. The flame sensor  was dirty,and a curved white pipe outside on the roof had snow inside it. The tech drilled a hole in the furnace door so you could see the red "code" light.
[image]

As he had taken the module out before(to replace the fan, and never put it back properly). So you had to take the door off to see the light on the module. I placed sheet metal tape over the hole as l felt uncomfortable with the "repair". There is a Co2 detector 12 ft away which didn't go on before l covered the hole(or now).

Should l go for a more permanent repair to cover the hole drilled, or leave it? Should l call the tech back to repair the hole? I could use a magnet also. As l understand it isn't "code".

Another positive: the oil-canning stopped. The furnace seems to run slightly longer after the thermostat "clicks", but the loud metal bang is gone now.

Comment: We would need a photo to know, however a open combustion furnace having a view port added would not violate code. Could you provide the code reference you are talking about and include a photo.

Comment: It stopped oil-canning because they changed the filter. Which if you do that more often you'll have to call them less.

Comment: I replace my filter every month.

Comment: That's a colossal waste, even for cheap fiber filters. Take some stress off the environment and back off to every three.

Comment: So if the filter turns gray, that's ok?

Comment: Well, that means it's doing its job, but it doesn't mean you have to immediately replace it. Color isn't a problem. A thick buildup is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem. In a healthy furnace, combustion gases are contained inside various components housed in the *upper* cabinet.

If you think through the airflow path of your HVAC system, there's normally a vacuum on the lower chamber of the furnace cabinet because it's part of the return duct--it contains the fan. That means that air is drawn *into* that space, joins all the other incoming return air, and passes through the furnace's heat exchanger and out through the main exit trunk. A tiny hole just creates a miniscule return path from the furnace room.

I've done exactly this with one of my furnaces after upgrading the circuit board to one with an indicator, so that I could see the indicator from outside. I applied clear packaging tape over the 3/4" hole I made just for the heck of it. I put two pieces back to back to eliminate the exposed adhesive, then I framed that with tape on the inside of the panel. It held well. Obviously you don't want to use anything that could get drawn into the fan cage.

Comment: I also don’t see a issue. I usually use a piece of plexiglass for viewports but the clear tape back to back should also meet “finger safe” rules.  having a slug screwed in so you rotate it to look in also works and a 3rd option. I was still wondering about the “code” statement.+

Comment: My brother who installs furnaces(and live 2000 miles away) told me that drilling a hole into the lower door of the furnace doesn't meet "code'. I don't know if code means everywhere ,or specifically Canada. I could email him and ask.

Comment: What about a round magnet? Easy to put on and take off. But not the best seal?

Comment: Can't really see through a magnet. If you like, though. As I said, the hole doesn't need to be closed in the first place, so whatever.

Comment: "I applied clear packaging tape", +1. Otherwise it's bypassing the filter.

Comment: The "code" statement was from  my brother meaning furnaces aren't shipped with a hole in the door. I"m sure he could have used a different word than code. Maybe "stock"?

Comment: Well, technically _any_ modification to a UL listed product voids its listing status, and thus code compliance. Doesn't mean it's an actual problem.

Comment: The furnace tech was back 2 weeks later as l had no heat. Reset the power to the furnace but that didn't help. He cleaned the "burner wire", which l cleaned 2 weeks ago, with steel wool. He used a wire brush to clean the wire,and the furnace worked. He also told me to NEVER use sandpaper to clean the wire as the glue leaves a film on the wire.